# WP Gravity Forms - Hiding decimals when equal to ,00

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

I want to hide decimals if they're -,00. But if they're -,75 for example, I want them to show

```
function gf_update_currency( $currencies ) {

    if(in_array('decimals', $currencies['EUR'])== 00) {
        $decimals = 0
    } else {
        $decimals = 2;
    }

    $currencies['EUR'] = array(
        'name' => __( 'Euro', 'gravityforms' ),
        'symbol_left' => '€',
        'symbol_right' => '',
        'symbol_padding' => '',
        'thousand_separator' => '.',
        'decimal_separator' => ',',
        'decimals' => $decimals

    );
    return $currencies;
}
add_filter( 'gform_currencies', 'gf_update_currency' );
```

I've tried variations of this, like transforming it into a string to check if it ends with -,00. But they won't work.

EDIT: I've also tried editing the field price directly but I don't quite understand how to select a Price Option field.

Comment: `$number = preg_replace('/\,00$/', '', $number)` - the `$` matches end of string.  Or `preg_match` - if you just want to check.

Comment: I'm a noob, so where should this be placed?

Comment: Why do you check in the first line of your code whether `in_array` returns `00`? What should that line do?

Comment: See this [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2606af175aa1e94c3c56c845b52e596a8d84361c) - `I'm a noob, so where should this be placed`  How should I know, I can only see a tiny bit of your code.  you asked how to match `,00` so I show you.

Comment: @NicoHaase My idea was that if the decimals are -,00 this should make them leave, and if it was anything else than that it would leave the 2 decimals. I figured out this doesn't work like that, because the array doesn't contain those values. Rather the price, but I don't understand how to access the price directly.

Comment: `, because the array doesn't contain those values` - what does it contain then.

Comment: Well, `in_array` returns either `true` or `false`, nothing else. That line checks whether `$currencies['EUR']` contains the string `decimals`

Comment: You cannot conditionally set it until you know if the number will have those decimals or not, so you will have to change it after the fact, no?

Comment: @NicoHaase I see. I will really have to access the price of a product then.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It contains the amount of decimals. -,00 = 2, -,000 = 3. So now what I have to do is figure out a way to get the price of a product, then use the bit of code you sent me to replace it with an empty string.